# Stopping text from wrapping around image

Tags: html, css

I am destroying my mind trying to get this styling done right.  I have a fixed size image with an unpredictable height div of text to the right of it.  I want the top of the text to line up with the top of the image but to NOT wrap around it. My markup is:

```
<img height='231px' width='132px' style='float:left' />
<div>Text</div>
```

I would like to find a solution that doesn't involve using a table, but at the moment I am drained and can't think about how to do it with css/divs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<div style="margin-left: 132px">Text</div>
```

To have space between the text and the image, make the margin larger or add a `padding-left`.

Comment: Exactly...except it should be `margin-left:132px;`... `231` is the height.

Comment: +1 very simple solution - see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/5RmMF/)! PS. I copied that text from the Guardian website, before you get suspicious... :)

Answer (score 2):

DanielB's answer nails it, but I just like giving alternative solutions; never know if it might come in handy. You could put the image and the div into a container with a fixed width, set a fixed width on the image and div that adds up to the container's width, and float the div as well.

```
<div id="container">
    <img height='231px' width='123px' style='float:left' />
    <div>Text</div>
</div>
#container div 
{
    float:left;   
    width: 123px;
}
#container {
 width:246px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/A7ZHg/3/

Comment: This is a decent alternative, but is significantly more code and does not size the text div to its parent container as nicely.

Comment: @Dutchie yup, i know. In this particular situation, Daniel's solution is much better, for sure. I just like throwing out generic alternatives sometimes. :)

Comment: More code, but this is more flexible, and lets the image size change, or indeed, lets the builder chain a bunch of text and images together if they want to.

Comment: downvoter: please leave a comment explaining your downvote so that I can improve my answer.